# ES Stack Exchange's Mineral Guide

Tags: feature-request, tags, answers

**Project is closed by the system. We could move it to github, but the point I saw is there are a lot of good geologists at the site. I am sugesting to take from an own server one monthly data request from a abcd questions post and make the app, as I think specialy the quiz could become huge quality in collaborative mode. But it looks death with no interest neither from site. To try to move some high quality editors as doctors to other site/project would be beating about the bush.**

"We're getting really far afield here. I'd suggest that if you want to organize a project like this, use chat - meta isn't exactly the right tool for it. – hichris123♦"

I cannot delete the question but I deleted the sheets. I am sorry for the inconveniences. ul

> This post lists the minerals identified at "identify-request" tag, as
>   a proposal to have some kind of guide....

Comment: I asked for the app and there is any trouble quoting ccc license. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316654/can-we-make-a-free-app-on-earth-sciences-exchange-with-information-from-posts

Comment: Project closed "We're getting really far afield here. I'd suggest that if you want to organize a project like this, use chat - meta isn't exactly the right tool for it. – hichris123♦ " I can't delete the question

Comment: @Gimelist. I think this clarifies as a full explanation of what I had in mind. I apologize for your time and for my little troubles expanding my text disorderly. Greetings from "the antípodas :)"

Answer (score 2):

While I appreciate the effort, is this really required?

Does the internet need yet another mineral-id? We can't beat [mindat](https://www.mindat.org/) or [webmineral](http://webmineral.com/), so why bother? Those websites have a huge database of images, full listing of the mineral properties, etc etc etc. There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Furthermore, our identifications are usually based on poorly photographed images and poorly described questions. All mineral identifications on this website should be taken with a grain of salt. An attempt to "formalise" it serves no purpose in my opinion.

Comment: My english. Resume. If we fill some info of each mineral I can write an application for Android and iOS. My guess is we would reach 5.000 users. Unfortunately I think anybody is gonna fill anything. But I am gonna try it. I have halfy of the app code written

Comment: @Universal_learner I don't see how this will attract new geology students to this website. I am involved in teaching, and I point my students to other resources. I never even mention the existence of this website. My feeling is that I'm not alone in this attitude.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly is it that you're trying to do, and how does Google Scholar and ScienceDirect fit into this, but I think that I do understand that you want to use the questions and answers contributed to this site by others, for your own financial gain. Even if legal (since SE is CC), I would personally find it obnoxious behaviour, and actively and strongly discourage anyone from answering questions until you stop doing so.

Comment: Exactly (I don't know your programming knowledges). Open source code application (WITH PUBLIC DOMAIN LICENSE) that makes a get petition to this post url. Takes the links to the minerals. Shows the question, the top answer, and, if you wish, we could fill some extra values. They are realy happy with my purposal! They say it is encouraged but CC license says to link authors is necesary. btw I wouldn't publish it on google store without activity -wich is gonna happen- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316654/can-we-make-a-free-app-on-earth-sciences-exchange-with-information-from-posts

Comment: @Universal_learner I don't care what they say. I refuse to allow my answers on your app. Period. I have no way to enforce it, but just letting you know that I am very displeased with this.

Comment: Ok so I quit every sheet that is answered by you. The test is just the archi for other sites and the app is not going to be installed by anybody I guess. Just the code will be at github we will be an example

Comment: @Universal_learner as I said, I cannot enforce it, and it is legal because of the licence. I just find it extremely unethical to do so, when the user who posted it (myself) is not happy with it. I suspect many other users who regularly answer these questions will be likewise unhappy with your use of their answers. Perhaps make it opt-in, not opt-out.

Comment: I finish. You can ask me everything about it on the chat not going to post anywhere any of your text if you don't wish it.I understand you don't associate your account with your professional skill,but sometimes people as @Gary Kindel may be writing with CC license because he wants to appear helping the forum.So in the oposite way some users would may accept as a great new their posts are at a FREE app that is being readed by 2000 students.But it looks like,as I said the guide will no go on so no worries.Just gonna see if it interest the site-it is realy nice to enter on a collaborative project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84415/discussion-between-gimelist-and-universal-learner).

Comment: @Universal_learner see additional comments in chat, and continue there please.

Comment: Gimelist you don't worry about science direct because you are a teacher on first world. Ask it to an african student if it would be nice that users with reputation had access to the articles that teachers as you quote. About google scholar and rigth author be sure at 2025 there would some printing advances. Then the site could be nice for those it is designed for: students. With a bit more of quality